# Software to manage one's resume

Tags: pdf, cloud-service

What are good software options to manage one's resume?

Specifically, a tool that lets you input all of your information; is viewable online by a prospective employer; and lets you generate a finished PDF, with formatting options, options to remove some pieces, etc.

Stack Overflow Careers used to meet these criteria, but the new "Developer Story" seems to have utterly given up on the PDF generation aspect, which is crucial for many people.

Comment: If you use Windwos 10, or Libre Office, you have "print to PDF" for free

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you can check this out:

[VisualCV](https://www.visualcv.com/)
 guarantees you will always make the right first impression. Choose from a variety of industry-approved templates, create multiple profile versions, and track the results. You can even edit your CV on your mobile device.

1. Choose your design
   VisualCV template is carefully crafted to get you from application to interview.
2. Create custom versions
   Customization is key. Easily manage multiple VisualCV versions, personalized for each application.
3. Track the results
   You can also get insight into your career success with VisualCV analytics, and get updated when your resume is viewed or downloaded.
4. platform
   It can be accessed from any web browser and costs come in depending on the number of accepted CVs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with (or want to get familiar with) LaTeX, https://www.latex-project.org/ , there are many, many resume, cv, etc templates, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae These will "natively" give you your pdf's.

For web-based stuff, there are LaTeX-to-html converters galore, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/convert-latex-to-html Or google "latex to html" for tons of other stuff not mentioned on that stackexchange question.

I haven't used the VisualCV stuff suggested above. It looks nice and lots more automated for its more narrowly-defined purpose. The LaTeX stuff either requires more work **from** you, or else gives more flexibility **to** you, depending on your point of view.

Answer (score 1):

If you need another recommendation, I can recommend **[Resumonk](https://www.resumonk.com/)**.

Resumonk is online resume maker. They provides resume templates so you can make your own resume easily. The generated resume can be exported to PDF. You can even share your resume online and manage it. But, these features are not available for free tier. I would suggest to look forward this [pricing page](https://www.resumonk.com/pricing) to see what features are supported by different tiers.

I second John Forkosh's idea. If you are familiar with LaTeX, I really recommend it. You create your resume with provided templates or hack your own resume. Note that it's not easy since you must have knowledge about LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about plain old HTML with CSS. I used a variety of other fancy approaches for writing my CV until I realized that HTML and CSS have everything I need and are pleasant to work with. [Here's the PDF version of my CV.](http://arfer.net/cv.pdf)

- lets you input all of your information — Check. Just type it in with a text editor.
- is viewable online by a prospective employer — Check. Put the HTML file on any host.
- lets you generated a finished PDF — Check. Firefox's print-to-PDF feature and WeasyPrint are both good tools for this. (I've typeset [a book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1523814535) with WeasyPrint, and lots of APA-style scientific manuscripts with Firefox.)
- with formatting options — Check. CSS is designed for this.
- options to remove some pieces — Check. HTML comments make this easy to do. Or keep your file under version control, as with Git. Then you can delete passages and revert or switch back to the main branch when you want the deleted stuff restored. I track my own CV with Git so I can see what it looked like at any time if I need to.